# Convert floating point $count to integer in Mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, aggregation

I have an aggregate query that essentially has this part in the code.

```
...
{ $group: { _id: "$category", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
...
```

However, once I get the result the count is showing up as floating-point values.

```
{
   "_id": "MENSWEAR",
   "count": 306.0
}
```

How to convert this to integer in the same line?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/

Comment: Thanks ... { $group: { _id: "$category", count: { $sum: {$toInt: 1} } } }. This worked!